# How to convert a 1D array to tuple in Julia?

Tags: arrays, tuples, julia, reshape, splat

I want to reshape an array in Julia using the `reshape` function but the shape of the new array is stored as a 1-D array itself. `reshape` takes tuples as argument but not 1D array.

For example, I want to be able to do this:

`reshape([1 2 3 ; 4 5 6],(3,2))`

but using `[3,2]` instead of `(3,2)` as the input to the shape parameter. Converting array `[3,2]` to tuple `(3,2)` seems like the obvious thing to do, but if that can't be done, maybe I need to write another `reshape` function?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [splat](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/faq/#The-two-uses-of-the-...-operator:-slurping-and-splatting-1) the array:

```
julia> reshape([1 2 3 ; 4 5 6], [3,2]...)
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  5
 4  3
 2  6
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need!

Comment: or - in other use cases when splatting would not be allowed `Tuple(array)` creates a tuple from an array.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński That solution also works great. Thanks! I wish Julia documentation mentions that as a constructor method for tuples.

Answer (score 2):

```
function array2tuple(a::Array)
   (a...,)
end
```